# Detailed android activity lifecycle (onAttachedToWindow())

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

I'm interested in android activity lifecycle and I would like to get more detailed description/documentation/reference than widely available basic (onCreate->onStart->onResume) [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

My need comes from realizing that starting new activity (`Theme.Dialog` styled) from `onAttachedToWindow()` greatly improves response time if comparing to starting it from onCreate(). I wonder how this `onAttachedToWindow()` fits into whole android activity lifecycle. Official API ref description *"Called when the window has been attached to the window manager"* doesn't help a lot.

Comment: If you want to see how it fits in with the other methods, you could override each of the methods and add some print statements.

Comment: Yes, I've done that (onAttachedToWindow() goes after onResume()). But that doesn't give answer to *what exactly happens?* and *why such a difference in responsiveness?*.

Comment: When does OnCreate event start to run exactly? When I set a breakpoint at beginning of OnCreate event so app run and loads activity to screen then breakpoint activates and the app goes to pause. I need an event about the activity that activates exactly before activity initialized and launched.

Answer (score 6):

My guess for why that feels more responsive, off the top of my head: I think that if you start Activity B from activity A's onCreate(), Activity A isn't drawn before activity B starts, which may take another second or two (making the app feel less responsive), where if you start activity B in Activity A's onAttachedToWindow(), A is started and rendered before B is kicked off, so the user doesn't have to sit for a second with a blank screen or the pre-A activity before seeing a reaction to their action.

Comment: Your explanation does seem to correspond with what is happening, but I still don't get why doing *more work* (pre-A > A.onCreate(), A.onStart(), A.onResume(), A.onAttachedToWindow() > B) is faster than starting B from A.onCreate() (pre-A > A.onCreate() > B). Loading time from pre-A to B is <1s and ~7s respectively.

Answer (score -3):

1. When the activity is launched, the `onCreate()` method is called. In the `onCreate()` method you perform basic startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of the activity.
2. After `onCreate()` is executed, the  `onStart()` method is called. This method makes the activity **visible** as the app prepares the activity to enter the foreground and become interactive.
3. After `onStart()` is executed, the `onResume()` method is called. This method is called only when the app is in the **foreground** because this is the state in which the app interacts with the user. The app stays in the resumed (or running) state until something happens to take focus away from the app.
4. If another activity comes into the **foreground**, the `onPause()` method is called. The app is paused if it is still **visible**. This method only pauses the operations of the activity. It does not destroy. The activity remains in the paused state until either the activity resumes or becomes completely invisible to the user.  *4a*. If the user returns to the activity, the 
   `onResume()` method is called again.  *4b*. the app process can be killed from the paused state if apps with higher priority need memory. If the user needs to return to app after it is killed, the `onCreate()` method is called again
5. If the activity is no longer **visible** to the user, the `onStop()` method is called. When the activity is stopped, the activity object is kept in memory and maintains all state and information but is not attached to the window manager.
   *5a*. if the user returns to the activity, the `onRestart()` method is called, followed by the `onStart()` method again.
   *5b*. the app process can be killed from the stopped state if apps with higher priority need memory. If the user needs to return to the app after it is killed, the `onCreate()` method is called again.
6. If the activity is finishing or being killed by the system, the `onDestroy()` method is called. The app is not initially shut down. The system either calls this method because the activity is finishing due to someone’s calling `finish()`, or because the system is temporarily destroying the process containing the activity to save space. The system may also call this method when an orientation change occurs, and then immediately call `onCreate()` to recreate the process (and the components that it contains) in the new orientation. The `onDestroy()` method releases all resources that have not yet been released by earlier methods such as `onStop()`.

The **entire lifetime** of an activity happens between the first call to `onCreate()` through a single final call to `onDestroy()`.

The **visible lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to `onStart()` until a call to `onStop()`.

The **foreground lifetime** of an activity happens between a call to `onResume()` until a call to `onPause()`.

The only method we must implement is `onCreate()`. The others are called automatically. But we can implement them ourselves to tell the app what to do during those processes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#asem

`onAttachedToWindow` is called when the view is attached to a window. At this point it has a Surface and will start drawing.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow()