# What is the exact difference between onAttachedToWindow and onStart

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, oncreate

I sometimes see people using the `Activity.onAttachedToWindow` method but personally, I did never use it. When reading it's documentation it appears to me as it would be almost the same as `onStart()`.

One thing I assume is:
`onAttachedToWindow` is invoked before `onCreate()`
`onStop` is invoked after.

Am I right with this assumption?
What are the behalfs of both and when do you use which?

Comment: for onStart()/onStop() see this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[onAttachedToWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow%28%29):

> This is called when the view is attached to a window. At this point it
>   has a Surface and will start drawing. Note that this function is
>   guaranteed to be called before onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas),
>   however it may be called any time before the first onDraw -- including
>   before or after onMeasure(int, int).

[Activity Lifecycle is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516056/265167).

I found that "[starting new activity (Theme.Dialog styled) from onAttachedToWindow() greatly improves response time if comparing to starting it from onCreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038130/detailed-android-activity-lifecycle-onattachedtowindow)"